# Crash in FixMath and MachineExceptions.h after adding AudioToolbox.framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, frameworks, core-audio

Made a new window application.  Right-clicked Frameworks > Add Existing Frameworks. Selected Frameworks folder, then AudioToolbox.framework.
Build, and 11 crashes.

```
#elif defined __ppc__ || __ppc64__

#define _IntSaturate(x) ((int) (x))

#else

#error "Unknown architecture."
// To use unoptimized standard C code, remove above line.
#define _IntSaturate(x) ((x) <= -0x1p31f ? (int) -0x80000000 : \
    0x1p31f <= (x) ? (int) 0x7fffffff : (int) (x))

#endif
```

Tried commenting that line, then MachineExceptions still crashes:

```
typedef CALLBACK_API_C( OSStatus , ExceptionHandlerProcPtr )(ExceptionInformation * theException);
```

error: expected ")" before '*' token

..what the hell happened? I'm 99.9% sure I've never modified the AudioToolbox or any other framework.

Comment: You're saying "crash" but it sounds like what you're really asking about is a compilation error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scrapped the project, copied main classes and everything working smoothly again.